# Decreasing coefficients?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

For any integer $n\ge 3$, let $P(x)=\sum\limits_{i(=2k)\ge 0}^{n}\binom{n}{2k}(1-x)^k$, $Q(x)=\sum\limits_{i(=2k+1)\ge 0}^{n}\binom{n}{2k+1}(1-x)^{k+1}$. Define $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\equiv\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}c_ix^i $. I like to know $c_0> c_1> c_2>\cdots$, but I don't know how to show it.

Comment: Your notation for the sums defining P and Q is quite nonstandard and confusing, but I think I understand what you mean. Just to make sure: do you mean to sum over all integers k for which 0≤2k≤n (in the first sum) and 0≤2k+1≤n (in the second sum)? Also, what reasons (if any) do you have for assuming the desired result is true?

Comment: Under Harald's guess as to the meaning, for $n=2$ we get $P=2-x$ and $Q=2(1-x)$, so that $P/Q=1/2(1+1/(1-x))$, whose coefficients are not strictly decreasing. So, if Harald was right, either miwalin meant for $n>2$ or for $c_0 \geq c_1 \geq c_2 \geq \dots$.

Comment: @Bryant: Right, if $n>2$, the coefficients are strictly decreasing.

Comment: @ Olsen: Yes, you got it. The result is useful in determining the convergence range of a functional iteration. I tried some examples on matlab for $n=3,4,5$.

Comment: Can you write a (linear) recursion for $c_i$'s (fixed $n$)?

Comment: @ Zudilin: I wish I could, but I failed many times and gave up this attempt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The polynomials $P_n$ and $Q_n$ can be written as
$$
P_n(x)=(1+\sqrt{1-x})^n+(1-\sqrt{1-x})^n,
\qquad
Q_n(x)=\sqrt{1-x}\bigl((1+\sqrt{1-x})^n-(1-\sqrt{1-x})^n\bigr).
$$
In particular, they are both solutions to the linear difference equation
$P_{n+1}(x)=2P_n(x)-xP_{n-1}(x)$ implying that their quotient
$f_n(x)=P_n(x)/Q_n(x)$ satisfies the nonlinear recursion
$$
f_{n+1}(x)=\frac{1+f_n(x)}{1+(1-x)f_n(x)}
$$
(already observed experimentally by Martin Rubey).

The property saying that the coefficients of the power series
$f(x)=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+\dots$ satisfy $c_0\ge c_1\ge c_2\ge\dots$
can be rephrased as $c_0-(1-x)f(x)\ge0$, where the record
$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots\ge0$ means that all $a_i\ge0$. This makes
the original problem equivalent to $1-(1-x)f_n(x)\ge0$ for all $n$.
This follows by induction on $n$. The base of induction is clear
verification (already done by the author for a few first $n$).
Assuming that it is true for a given $n$ and using that the
non-negative expansion $1-(1-x)f_n(x)$ has the vanishing constant term,
we conclude that the (formal) power series
$$
\frac1{1-\frac12\bigl(1-(1-x)f_n(x)\bigr)}
=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2^k}\bigl(1-(1-x)f_n(x)\bigr)^k
$$
is non-negative. It remains to apply the above recursion for $f_n(x)$:
$$
1-(1-x)f_{n+1}(x)
=\frac x{1+(1-x)f_n(x)}
=\frac x2\cdot\frac1{1-\frac12\bigl(1-(1-x)f_n(x)\bigr)},
$$
and the desired property follows.

Comment: A very good proof. 

Comment: Thanks, miwanlin! Controry to my predictions it seems to be non-technical.

Answer (score 1):

(Not an answer - but too large for a comment) here are recurrences for the first few n.  I don't have time right now to look at them, but shouldn't be hard to spot a pattern...

```
(1) -> P n == reduce(+, [binomial(n, 2*k)*(1-x)^k for k in 0..n | 2*k Q n == reduce(+, [binomial(n, 2*k+1)*(1-x)^(k+1) for k in 0..n | 2*k+1 n:=3; guessPRec(entries complete first(coefficients series(P n/Q n, x=0), 10))

   (3)  [[f(n): - 4f(n + 1) + f(n) + 1= 0,f(0)= 1]]

(4) -> n:=4; guessPRec(entries complete first(coefficients series(P n/Q n, x=0), 10))

   (4)  [[f(n): - 8n f(n + 1) + 4n f(n) + n= 0,f(0)= 1]]

(5) -> n:=5; guessPRec(entries complete first(coefficients series(P n/Q n, x=0), 30))

                                                                      1
   (5)  [[f(n): - 16f(n + 2) + 12f(n + 1) - f(n) + 1= 0,f(0)= 1,f(1)= -]]
                                                                      2

(6) -> n:=6; guessPRec(entries complete first(coefficients series(P n/Q n, x=0), 30))

   (6)
                                                                        1
   [[f(n): - 32n f(n + 2) + 32n f(n + 1) - 6n f(n) + n= 0,f(0)= 1,f(1)= -]]
                                                                        2

(7) -> n:=7; guessPRec(entries complete first(coefficients series(P n/Q n, x=0), 30))

   (7)
   [
     [f(n): 64f(n + 3) - 80f(n + 2) + 24f(n + 1) - f(n) - 1= 0, f(0)= 1,
            1        3
      f(1)= -, f(2)= -]
            2        8
     ]

(8) -> n:=8; guessPRec(entries complete first(coefficients series(P n/Q n, x=0), 100))

   (8)
   [
     [f(n): 128n f(n + 3) - 192n f(n + 2) + 80n f(n + 1) - 8n f(n) - n= 0,
                     1        3
      f(0)= 1, f(1)= -, f(2)= -]
                     2        8
     ]

(9) -> n:=9; guessPRec(entries complete first(coefficients series(P n/Q n, x=0), 100))

   (9)
   [
     [f(n): - 256f(n + 4) + 448f(n + 3) - 240f(n + 2) + 40f(n + 1) - f(n) + 1= 0
       ,
                     1        3         5
      f(0)= 1, f(1)= -, f(2)= -, f(3)= --]
                     2        8        16
     ]

(10) -> n:=10; guessPRec(entries complete first(coefficients series(P n/Q n, x=0), 100))

   (10)
   [
     [
       f(n):
           - 512n f(n + 4) + 1024n f(n + 3) - 672n f(n + 2) + 160n f(n + 1)
         + 
           - 10n f(n) + n
           =
           0
       ,
                     1        3         5
      f(0)= 1, f(1)= -, f(2)= -, f(3)= --]
                     2        8        16
     ]

(11) -> n:=11; guessPRec(entries complete first(coefficients series(P n/Q n, x=0), 100))

   (11)
   [
     [
       f(n):
           1024f(n + 5) - 2304f(n + 4) + 1792f(n + 3) - 560f(n + 2) + 60f(n + 1)
         + 
           - f(n) - 1
           =
           0
       ,
                     1        3         5
      f(0)= 1, f(1)= -, f(2)= -, f(3)= --]
                     2        8        16
     ]
```

and, in case it helps, here is the (nonlinear) recurrence for the sequence of $P_n/Q_n$:

```
(19) -> guessRec([P n/Q n for n in 1..100])

                                                                     1
   (19)  [[f(n): ((- x + 1)f(n) + 1)f(n + 1) - f(n) - 1= 0,f(0)= - -----]]
                                                                   x - 1
```

Comment: $$\frac PQ=\sqrt{1-x}\frac{(1+\sqrt{1-x})^n+(1-\sqrt{1-x})^n}{(1+\sqrt{1-x})^n-(1-\sqrt{1-x})^n}$$

Comment: @Wadim: Your extra $\sqrt{1-x}$ should be in the denominator.

Comment: @Gerald: Thanks, I realised this after looking at the original question...

Comment: Direct expansion shows $\frac PQ=\frac{(1+\sqrt{1-x})^n+(1-\sqrt{1-x})^n}{\sqrt{1-x}[(1+\sqrt{1-x})^n-(1-\sqrt{1-x})^n]}$, how to see that the coefficients are decreasing?

Comment: The limit on $n$ has decreasing coefficients.

Comment: @ Edgar: That is the evidence for claiming the result is true.^_^

Comment: It's more than evidence. The polynomials $P_n(x)=(1+\sqrt{1-x})^n+(1-\sqrt{1-x})^n$ and $Q_n(x)=\sqrt{1-x}((1+\sqrt{1-x})^n-(1-\sqrt{1-x})^n)$ satisfy the same recursion $P_{n+1}=2P_n-xP_{n-1}$; their quotients $f_n(x)=P_n(x)/Q_n(x)$ form *convergents* to $1/\sqrt{1-x}$. Your property $f(x)=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+\dots$ satisfies $c_0\ge c_1\ge c_2\ge\dots$ can be stated as $c_0-(1-x)f\ge0$, where the record $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots\ge0$ means that all $a_i\ge0$. So, your problem is $1-(1-x)f_n(x)\ge0$ for all $n$; this happens eventually as $f_n(x)$ is close to $1/\sqrt{1-x}$.

Comment: The point is that your sequence $f_n(x)$ is monotonic in the following sense: $(1-x)(f_n(x)-f_{n+1}(x))\ge0$ for all $n$. This implies $1-(1-x)f_{n+1}(x)\ge1-(1-x)f_n(x)$, so that the inductive argument yields the required $1-(1-x)f_n(x)\ge0$. However, proving the monotonicity looks very boring to me (and even Martin's nonlinear recursion for $f_n$ is of no help), I do not think it can be done in a "beautiful" way. (I split my comment into two because of character limitation.)

Comment: @ Wadim: Perhaps you are right, but I don't give up finding a 'good' proof.

Comment: @miwalin: encouraged by your willing, I finally found a proof of the property. I probably have to remove my comments above but then the whole history will be represented wrong.